# Using grep to print line numbers

Tags: grep

I would like to use the grep command to print a line number for the string I'm searching for.  However, when I used the command `grep -n` it prints the line number with a colon : next to it.  Is there any way I can use the same `grep -n` command to print a line number with it being followed by the : colon?

```
$ grep -n 'Captain' sometextfile.txt
3: Captain America
```

I would like it to instead print,

```
3 Captain America
```

(without the ':' )

Any suggestions??

Comment: You cannot do it using grep options only. Try: `grep 'Captain' sometextfile.txt | cat -n`

Comment: @muru But the line numbers will still change to 1,2,3...

Comment: @RohithMadhavan Then you can reverse the order: `cat -n sometextfile.txt | grep ...`

Comment: @muru Yes. That will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sed` along with `grep` to achieve this.

`grep -n 'Captain' sometextfile.txt | sed 's/:/ /'`

This sed command finds the pattern `:` and replaces it with (a space).

General Syntax - `sed 's/find/replace/'`

This method will replace only the first occurence of `:` in each line with . Therefore, even if a line in the text file contains `:`, it will remain unaffected.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to delete the colon (and not replace it with a space), you can pipe the output of your grep statement through `tr`.  Your command would be something like:

`grep -n 'Captain' sometextfile.txt | tr -d ':'`

If you want to replace the colon with a space, you can use:

`grep -n 'Captain' sometextfile.txt | tr ':' ' '`

Though, as muru points out, this will remove any colons in the line.

Comment: And what if the matched lines contain `:`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try whether this command helps you

```
awk '/Captain America/ {printf "%s %s\n", NR, $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my two cents on the question, use awk sub function :

`grep -n 'Captain' file.txt | awk '{sub(":"," "); print }'`

`grep -n 'Captain' file | awk '{sub(":Captain"," Captain"); print }'`

And here's cut ( which removes all traces of `:` like in dazzle's example ):

`grep -n 'Captain' file  | cut -d":" -f1-  --output-delimiter=" "`